# How can I add a new entry to a ListView using QML?

Tags: qt, qml

How can I add a new "blank" entry to a ListView that is populated using a QObjectList-based model?
The documentation outlines that we can use QList<QObject*> to populate a model (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html), but I don't see anyway to add a new entry using this method...

I've made a sample program to show what I mean, the problem lies in the Main.qml's button onClick event.

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true


    ColumnLayout {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        ListView {
            id: listView
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            model: sampleManager.sampleObjList
            delegate: RowLayout {
                anchors.fill: listView

                Label {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    text: modelData.id
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Add New Entry"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            onClicked: function(mouse) {
                // How do I add a new entry to listView.model...
                // This says append does not exist...
                listView.model.append({});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "SampleManager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   SampleManager* sample_manager = new SampleManager();

   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("sampleManager", sample_manager);


   const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
   QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                    &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
      if (!obj && url == objUrl)
         QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
   }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
   engine.load(url);

   return app.exec();
}
```

**SampleManager.h**

```
#ifndef SAMPLEMANAGER_H
#define SAMPLEMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>

#include "QMLMacros.h"

#include "SampleObj.h"

class SampleManager :
      public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   QML_WRITABLE_PROPERTY(QList<SampleObj*>, sampleObjList)

public:
   explicit SampleManager(
         QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:


public slots:

private:
};

#endif // SAMPLEMANAGER_H
```

**SampleManager.cpp**

```
#include "SampleManager.h"
#include "SampleObj.h"

SampleManager::SampleManager(
      QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
{
   m_sampleObjList.append(new SampleObj(this));
   m_sampleObjList.append(new SampleObj(this));

   m_sampleObjList[0]->set_id(0);
   m_sampleObjList[1]->set_id(1);
}
```

**SampleObj.h**

```
#ifndef SAMPLEOBJ_H
#define SAMPLEOBJ_H

#include <QObject>

#include "QMLMacros.h"


class SampleObj : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   QML_WRITABLE_PROPERTY(int, id);

public:
   explicit SampleObj(
         QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:

private:

};

#endif // SAMPLEOBJ_H
```

**SampleObj.cpp**

```
#include "SampleObj.h"

SampleObj::SampleObj(
      QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent),
   m_id(0)
{

}
```

**QMLMacros.h** (Just some macros I found online for easily declaring a Q_PROPERTY)

```
#ifndef QMLMACROS_H
#define QMLMACROS_H
#include <QObject>

/*!
    \defgroup QT_QML_HELPERS Qt helper macros

Brings a couple of macros that can help saving development time,
    by avoiding manual code duplication, often leading to heavy copy-and-paste,
    which is largely error-prone and not productive at all.
                                           */


/*!
    \def QML_WRITABLE_PROPERTY(type, name)
    \ingroup QT_QML_HELPERS
    \hideinitializer
    \details Creates a \c Q_PROPERTY that will be readable / writable from QML.

    \param type The C++ type of the property
    \param name The name for the property

    It generates for this goal :
    \code
        {type} m_{name}; // private member variable
        {type} get_{name} () const; // public getter method
        void set_{name} ({type}); // public setter slot
        void {name}Changed ({type}); // notifier signal
    \endcode

    \b Note : Any change from either C++ or QML side will trigger the
   notification.
*/
#define QML_WRITABLE_PROPERTY(type, name)                                      \
protected:                                                                     \
  Q_PROPERTY(type name READ get_##name WRITE set_##name NOTIFY name##Changed)  \
private:                                                                       \
  type m_##name{};                                                              \
                                                                               \
public:                                                                        \
  type get_##name() const { return m_##name; }                                  \
Q_SIGNALS:                                                                     \
  void name##Changed(type name);                                               \
public Q_SLOTS:                                                                \
  void set_##name(type name) {                                                 \
    if (m_##name != name) {                                                    \
      m_##name = name;                                                         \
      emit name##Changed(m_##name);                                            \
    }                                                                          \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
private:


/*!
    \def QML_READONLY_PROPERTY(type, name)
    \ingroup QT_QML_HELPERS
    \hideinitializer
    \details Creates a \c Q_PROPERTY that will be readable from QML and writable
   from C++.

\param type The C++ type of the property
\param name The name for the property

It generates for this goal :
\code
    {type} m_{name}; // private member variable
    {type} get_{name} () const; // public getter method
    void update_{name} ({type}); // public setter method
    void {name}Changed ({type}); // notifier signal
\endcode

\b Note : Any change from C++ side will trigger the notification to QML.
*/
#define QML_READONLY_PROPERTY(type, name)                                      \
protected:                                                                     \
  Q_PROPERTY(type name READ get_##name NOTIFY name##Changed)                   \
private:                                                                       \
  type m_##name{};                                                             \
                                                                               \
public:                                                                        \
  type get_##name() const { return m_##name; }                                 \
  bool update_##name(type name) {                                              \
    bool ret = false;                                                          \
    if ((ret = m_##name != name)) {                                            \
      m_##name = name;                                                         \
      emit name##Changed(m_##name);                                            \
    }                                                                          \
    return ret;                                                                \
  }                                                                            \
Q_SIGNALS:                                                                     \
  void name##Changed(type name);                                               \
                                                                               \
private:


/*!
    \def QML_CONSTANT_PROPERTY(type, name)
    \ingroup QT_QML_HELPERS
    \hideinitializer
    \details Creates a \c Q_PROPERTY for a constant value exposed from C++ to
   QML.

    \param type The C++ type of the property
    \param name The name for the property

    It generates for this goal :
    \code
        {type} m_{name}; // private member variable
        {type} get_{name} () const; // public getter method
    \endcode

    \b Note : There is no change notifier because value is constant.
*/
#define QML_CONSTANT_PROPERTY(type, name)                                      \
protected:                                                                     \
  Q_PROPERTY(type name READ get_##name CONSTANT)                               \
private:                                                                       \
  type m_##name;                                                               \
                                                                               \
public:                                                                        \
  type get_##name() const { return m_##name; }                                 \
                                                                               \
private:



#define QML_LIST_PROPERTY(CLASS, NAME, TYPE)                                   \
public:                                                                        \
  static int NAME##_count(QQmlListProperty<TYPE> *prop) {                      \
    CLASS *instance = qobject_cast<CLASS *>(prop->object);                     \
    return (instance != NULL ? instance->m_##NAME.count() : 0);                \
  }                                                                            \
  static void NAME##_clear(QQmlListProperty<TYPE> *prop) {                     \
    CLASS *instance = qobject_cast<CLASS *>(prop->object);                     \
    if (instance != NULL) {                                                    \
      instance->m_##NAME.clear();                                              \
    }                                                                          \
  }                                                                            \
  static void NAME##_append(QQmlListProperty<TYPE> *prop, TYPE *obj) {         \
    CLASS *instance = qobject_cast<CLASS *>(prop->object);                     \
    if (instance != NULL && obj != NULL) {                                     \
      instance->m_##NAME.append(obj);                                          \
    }                                                                          \
  }                                                                            \
  static TYPE *NAME##_at(QQmlListProperty<TYPE> *prop, int idx) {              \
    CLASS *instance = qobject_cast<CLASS *>(prop->object);                     \
    return (instance != NULL ? instance->m_##NAME.at(idx) : NULL);             \
  }                                                                            \
  QList<TYPE *> get_##NAME##s(void) const { return m_##NAME; }                 \
                                                                               \
private:                                                                       \
  QList<TYPE *> m_##NAME;


/*!
    \def QML_ENUM_CLASS(name, ...)
    \ingroup QT_QML_HELPERS
    \hideinitializer
    \details Creates a class that contains a C++ enum that can be exposed to
   QML.

    \param name The name for the class
    \param ... The variadic list of values for the enum (comma-separated)

    It generates for this goal :
    \li The \c {name} C++ QObject-derived class
    \li The \c {name}::Type enumeration containing the values list
    \li The \c Q_ENUMS macro call to allow QML usage

    Example in use :
    \code
        QML_ENUM_CLASS (DaysOfWeek, Monday = 1, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday,
   Friday, Saturday, Sunday) \endcode

    \b Note : The QML registration using \c qmlRegisterUncreatableType() will
   still be needed.
*/
#define QML_ENU_CLASS(name, ...)                                              \
  class name : public QObject {                                                \
    Q_GADGET                                                                   \
  public:                                                                      \
    enum Type { __VA_ARGS__ };                                                 \
    Q_ENUMS(Type)                                                              \
  };

class QmlProperty : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
}; // NOTE : to avoid "no suitable class found" MOC note

#endif // QMLMACROS_H
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone will ever run into this issue, but I could not find a solution. Unfortunately, I was forced to use create my own version of QAbstractListModel in order to effectively manage a list consisting of 1 int and 1 string per row within QML :(. An overly complicated solution for a minor minor problem, not elegant at all unfortunately.